# ¿Cómo llamar función JavaScript desde Asp.Net Mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Mesecito invocar una función JS desde mi controlador pasándole un valor entero, específicamente lo que trato de hacer es establecer el valor de selección de un DropDownList.

Intente esto pero no me funciona...

Codigo C#

```
  int filter = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Filtro"]);
  ViewBag.Info = null;
  var informacionCountContractsFilter = _IContractsApiConsumer.InformacionConteoContratoFiltro(1, 2, filter);
  ViewBag.Info = informacionCountContractsFilter;
  ViewBag.Filtro = filter;
```

Codigo JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @ViewBag.Filtro;

    function SetSelectFilter() {
        document.getElementById("Filtro").selectedIndex = @ViewBag.Filtro;;
    }
</script>
```

Html

```
  <div class="search_categories">
                <div class="select">
                    <form method="POST" action="Index">
                        <select name="Filtro" id="Filtro" class="Filtro">
                            <option value="1">Special</option>
                            <option value="2">Cloud</option>
                            <option value="3">Active</option>
                            <option value="4">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Filter Proyects" class="btn" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Porque no usas ajax?

Comment: por que no se usarlo ?

Comment: Creo que deberías re-evaluar lo que estás haciendo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 En el HTML invoco la funcion js de nombre SetSelectFilter  en el evento onLoad

```
<body onload="SetSelectFilter()">
</body>
```

2 En el js declare la variable filtro y escribi la funcion SetSelectFilter donde asigno al select el valor de esta:

```
<script>
    let filtro = @ViewBag.Filtro;
    $('Filtro').val(filtro);

    function SetSelectFilter() {
        document.getElementById("Filtro").selectedIndex = filtro;
    }
</script>
```

3 En mi controlador asigno a Viebag.Filtro el valor para setear el Select

```
//my code *********EEMC******
                    _IContractsApiConsumer.SetAuthHeader(_tokenManager.Token);
                    string t = Request.Method;
                    **ViewBag.Filtro = 0;**
                    if (Request.Method == "GET")
                    {
                        ViewBag.Info = null;
                        var informacionCountContracts = _IContractsApiConsumer.InformacionConteoContrato(1, 2);
                        ViewBag.Info = informacionCountContracts;
                    }
                    else if (Request.Method == "POST")
                    {
                        int filter = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Filtro"]);
                        ViewBag.Info = null;
                        var informacionCountContractsFilter = _IContractsApiConsumer.InformacionConteoContratoFiltro(1, 2, filter);
                        ViewBag.Info = informacionCountContractsFilter;
                        **ViewBag.Filtro = filter - 1 ;**
                    }
  //***************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que usas una etiqueta script y en el servidor asignas el valor a un ViewBag así que obtendremos ese valor y lo guardaremos en una variable en javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
let filtro = '@ViewBag.Filtro'; 
function SetSelectFilter() { 
  document.getElementById("Filtro").selectedIndex = filtro;
} 
SetSelectFilter();
</script>
```

Ten en cuenta que funcionará solo cuando asignes un valor a `@ViewBag.Filtro` en el action que muestra tu pagina ya que este valor lo asigna el servidor antes de cargar la pagina luego cargada no puede establecerlo.

Comment: Es lo que nesecito cuando VieBag.Filtro tenga un valor lo asigne al Select...Pruebo tu respuesta y te comento

Comment: Que retorna ese código de c# es decir el action

Comment: retorna una vista con un modelo ..return View(model);

Comment: ¿Chévere, te funcionó?

Comment: No me esta funcionando ...  :(

Comment: Por que despues que devuelve el action se va a una vista parcial que se monta en la pagina y creo que por eso el valor de filtro se pierde ... ??'

Comment: Lo dudo pero agrega mas detalles de la parte del servidor a la pregunta.

Comment: Que mas te puedo agregar eso es casi todo el codigo, solo debo setear el index del select al valor de filter y listo...